# why is my output not correct while dividing by a variable in awk?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables, awk

I wrote a small watch script to monitor the load average on a Linux server (just for learning purposes but watch uptime wasn't giving the output I want).

It works well, but to get the load average for each core, I divide the load average values by the number of cores. This is now accomplished by hardcoding the cores, which is inconvenient if I choose to use it on another server.

Due to that, I want to have the cores done by variable like `nproc`.

All is well and good, but for some reason, my output is completely different when I use `nproc` as the core count than when I hard code the cores.

This is my script now:

```
#! /bin/bash
PATH=/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/csw/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin

while true
do
    uptime | awk '{ printf "%2.2f ",$(NF-2)/4 ; printf "%2.2f ",$(NF-1)/4  ; printf "%2.2f\n",$(NF)/4}'
        sleep 1
done
```

As you see I have divided the load average by 4 (4 core server). This gives me the following output:

```
$ ./watch-load.sh 
1.05 0.96 1.09
1.05 0.96 1.09
0.96 0.94 1.08
0.96 0.94 1.08
0.96 0.94 1.08
```

but when I edit the script to use `nproc` it looks something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
PATH=/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/csw/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin

while true
do
    uptime | awk '{ printf "%.2f ",$10/$(nproc) ; printf "%2.2f ",$11/$(nproc)  ; printf "%2.2f\n",$12/$(nproc)}'
        sleep 1
done
```

This will give me the following results:

```
$ ./watch-load-test.sh 
0.22 0.23 0.27
0.22 0.23 0.27
0.22 0.23 0.27
0.28 0.24 0.27
0.28 0.24 0.27
```

This is weird because `nproc` is showing 4 cores:

```
$ nproc
4
```

I'm lost here. Do you have any suggestions why it doesn't seem to work the way it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of awk, `$(nproc)` means the value of the `nproc`th field, where `nproc` is an awk variable. Since your awk code doesn't define such a variable, it evaluates to `$0`

```
$ echo '1 2 3' | awk '{print $(nproc)}'
1 2 3
```

If you want to pass the value of a shell command substitution `$(nproc)` into your awk code, you can do so using the `-v` command line syntax

Ex.

```
$ echo '1 2 3' | awk -v nproc=$(nproc) '{print nproc}'
2
```

Comment: that worked! thanks a lot! i was really at a loss about this...